# How to divide the same number on both sides of the equation?

Tags: equation-solving

The given equation is:

```
y^2 (1 - λ^2) + 
  a^2 λ^2 (-1 - (λ^2 (1 - λ^2))/(-1 + \
λ^2)^2) + (1 - λ^2) (x - (
     a λ^2)/(-1 + λ^2))^2 == 0
```

Note that this type of equation is in the form of a circle, so the coefficients in front of x ^ 2 and y ^ 2 are equal. My requirement is how to automatically identify the coefficient in front of x ^ 2 and y ^ 2, and divide the left and right sides of the equation by this coefficient at the same time. Of course, this coefficient is not 0. After processing, the coefficient in front of x ^ 2 and y ^ 2 is 1

I used this manually, but it is not an automatically found coefficient, it is manually entered and the result cannot be simplified.

```
ApplySides[#/(1 - λ^2) &, 
 y^2 (1 - λ^2) + 
   a^2 λ^2 (-1 - (λ^2 (1 - λ^2))/(-1 + \
λ^2)^2) + (1 - λ^2) (x - (
      a λ^2)/(-1 + λ^2))^2 == 0]
```

the result is:

```
(y^2 (1 - λ^2) + 
  a^2 λ^2 (-1 - (λ^2 (1 - λ^2))/(-1 + \
λ^2)^2) + (1 - λ^2) (x - (
     a λ^2)/(-1 + λ^2))^2)/(1 - λ^2) == 0
```

Comment: Try: `Coefficient[equation[[1]], x^2]`

Comment: How to deal with simplification?

Comment: I wrote an answer for this

Answer (score 1):

Simplify will change the structure of the equation. Therefore we only work on the right hand side.

To get the coefficient of x^2 we use:

```
eq = y^2 (1 - \[Lambda]^2) + 
   a^2 \[Lambda]^2 (-1 - (\[Lambda]^2 (1 - \[Lambda]^2))/(-1 + \
\[Lambda]^2)^2) + (1 - \[Lambda]^2) (x - (a \[Lambda]^2)/(-1 + \
\[Lambda]^2))^2 == 0;
Coefficient[eq[[1]], x^2]
```

Now we can divide the RHS by this what gives the equation in the requested form:

```
eq[[1]] = eq[[1]]/Coefficient[eq[[1]], x^2] // Simplify;
eq
```

[image]

Comment: This method is not universal. If the right side of the original equation is not 0, it will not work